# ld: library not found for -l-lruby.1.9.1 while bundle install

Tags: ruby-on-rails, bundle, bundler

I am doing a bundle install operation. Facing issue when installing mysql gem
ld: library not found for -l-lruby.1.9.1
clang: error: linker command failed with exit code 1 (use -v to see invocation)

Couldn't find /usr/local/lib/libruby*.dylib file in my local

Is there any other additional package that needs to be installed?

Answer (score 0):

Are you using mac os? 
Try with this

```
xcode-select --install
```

Comment: Yes. I am using Mac OS. Getting output: xcode-select: error: command line tools are already installed, use "Software Update" to install updates